# See delegates for a particular account

Tags: spl-token, delegate

If I were to delegate an amount of spl tokens to a certain pubkey, how can I see (in the future) how much is there left as delegated token amount and which was the pubkey I delegated to?

Answer (score 1):

#### On the Command Line

```
$ spl-token -um account-info --address <TOKEN-ACCOUNT>
```

Will query mainnet (`-ud` for devnet, `-ul` for localnet) for that token account and print to the console.

#### Typescript

Use the `getAccount` function in `@solana/spl-token`. https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/js/src/state/account.ts#L95

#### Rust

Use the `anchor-spl` crate. (client is a `solana_client::rpc_client::RpcClient`, see https://docs.rs/solana-client/latest/solana_client/rpc_client/struct.RpcClient.html)

```
let token_act = client.get_account_data(&pubkey)?;
let token_act = anchor_spl::token::TokenAccount::try_deserialize(&mut token_act.as_slice())?;
```

#### Python

https://github.com/kevinheavey/anchorpy/blob/09e88c204cd5d3cd0b56c32b2cadc715f9bb8c58/src/anchorpy/utils/token.py#L234